# Difference between Scala.math vs Scala.Math Classes

Tags: scala

What is the different between `scala.math` and `scala.Math` classes both contain methods are look similer but `scala.math` has more i want to know what are the different between those two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first big difference is, that `Math` is an object, while `math` is a package.

The package `scala.math` contains additional `classes`, `objects` and `traits`, like `BigInt` and others (see scaladoc for more examples), which enables additional things(bigger numbers etc).

As one can see in the scala-doc: `scala.Math` is deprecated, you shouldn't use it anymore. 
You should use `scala.math`, which is the newer Version, and as you noticed, contains more functions.